# how to get spsite title only

Tags: spsite

Right now my code gets the URL from my SPSite but I only want to get the Title

```
var url = portalUrl.Text;
if (SPSite.Exists(new Uri(url)))
{
    using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite(url))
    {

        SPSiteCollection collWebsite = oSiteCollection.WebApplication.Sites;


        foreach (SPSite site in collWebsite)
        {
            listboxLogging.Items.Add(SPEncode.HtmlEncode(site + Environment.NewLine));
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only `SPWeb` has a title. You can get that from the context.

```
SPContext.Current.Web.Title
```

Comment: With his code, SPSite.RootWeb.Title